# Gitlab ip address in pipeline execution

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to set a static gitlab ip address while execution of a pipeline.
From guide I see that gitlab use random ip address in the range : **34.74. 90.64  -  34.74. 226.0**. But is not true, in my examination I see also ip address that started from 35.X.X.X.

Anyway, there is a way to know the correct range, or will be better, set a static gitlab ip?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitLab's shared runners do not guarantee any particular IP address will be used. The fact that GitLab runners happen run on GCP can give you some clues: the IP address will be one that belongs to GCP. Google publishes (and regularly updates) all their possible IP ranges for each region [published here](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json).

If you must have a static IP for your runners, you would need to self-host your runners on a platform that offers static IP addresses.